# Why is my static site broken using github action and azure cli to deploy?

Tags: vue.js, azure-storage, github-actions, azure-cli, static-site

I'm trying to deploy my static site to Azure storage but have been having issues getting the site open correctly even though the github action executes without errors and the files seem to be in place. In the browser, `index.html` seems to load along with the css and js.... but the site does not run properly. The console shows a failure in the js:
[image]

The odd thing is that I don't have any issues using the [azure storage extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurestorage) in vscode or using the azure cli:

`az storage blob upload-batch --account-name <ACCOUNT_NAME> -d '$web' -s ./dist --connection-string '<CONNECTION_STRING>'`

when I deploy from my laptop.

My github action looks like this:

```
name: Blob storage website CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: npm install
        run: |
          npm install
      - name: npm build
        run: |
          npm run build
      - name: Azure Login
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
      - name: Azure CLI script
        uses: azure/CLI@v1
        with:
          azcliversion: latest
          inlineScript: |
            az storage blob upload-batch --account-name <ACCOUNT_NAME> -d '$web' -s ./dist --connection-string '${{ secrets.BLOB_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING }}'
          # Azure logout
      - name: logout
        run: |
          az logout
```

based on [this article here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-static-site-github-actions).

I thought that it might be due to the azure cli version, but none of the versions I've tried have made a difference.

Any ideas why my site broken using github action and azure cli to deploy?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested - I was missing environment variables during the build process in the GitHub Action. I was able to pass these without checking in the `.env` files using github secrets.

There's now a step in the action to create a `.env`,

```
- name: Set Environment Variables
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=${{secrets.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}} >> .env
```

and another to remove it:

```
- name: Remove Environment Variables
        run: |
          rm .env
```